# Смена формата даты-время и перевод на utc

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Данные с датой и временем приходят в формате: `csv_dt = '2022.02.27 11:19:07'` (время по мск +3:00)

А в БД должны передаваться так: `db_dt = '2022-02-27 08:19:07.000000 +00:00'`
млсек - не важны.

Подскажите, плиз, как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

разобрался сам:

```
exmpl = '2022.02.01 11:19:07'

def handler(start_dt):
    result = datetime.fromisoformat(str(start_dt).replace('.', '-') + '+03:00')
    return result.astimezone(timezone.utc)


handler(exmpl)  # 2022-02-01 08:19:07+00:00
```